# Function fails on empty sequence

Tags: python

I am trying to find the date of the newest file in a directory, based on some Python code I shamelessly found on this site.

```
def newest_file_in_tree(rootfnewer, extension=".avi"):
    return max(
        (os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootfnewer)
        for filename in filenames
        if filename.endswith(extension)),
        key=lambda fn: os.stat(fn).st_mtime)
```

This works, but fails on empty directories.

```
    key=lambda fn: os.stat(fn).st_mtime)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

I concede that I am a Python beginner, and the last line is way beyond my pay grade.

Can anyone suggest how I can trap the error and prevent the function from crashing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can separate out that monstrously pythonic one liner into two separate lines, to make sure that `max` is called only when you have a non-empty list of files from which you pick the newest one:

```
def newest_file_in_tree(rootfnewer, extension=".avi"):
    files = [
        os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootfnewer)
        for filename in filenames
        if filename.endswith(extension)
    ]

    if files:
        return max(files, key=lambda fn: os.stat(fn).st_mtime)

    return None
```

Not as pretty as @hiroprotagonist's solution, but is more readable.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yesss! Testing the truthiness of an empty list. Updated, thank you.

Comment: I like this because it unclutters the code and is nicely explicit about what is happening.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Agreed. An even nicer (albeit less pythonic) solution would be removing the nested loops from that comprehension!

Answer (score 7):

[`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#max) has a `default` keyword:

```
m = max([], key=lambda x: abs(x), default='empty...')
print(m) # 'empty...'
```

the `default` will be returned if the iterable is empty. without the `default` this would raise a `ValueError`.

---

a different way for you to go would be to use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) in order to list the files:

```
import os
from glob import glob

def newest_file_in_tree(rootdir, ext='.avi'):
    glob_wildcard = os.path.join(rootdir, '**/*{}'.format(ext))
    glob_gen = glob(glob_wildcard, recursive=True)
    return max(glob_gen, key=lambda fn: os.stat(fn).st_mtime, default='?')
```

or even more concise with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

def newest_file_in_tree(rootpath, ext='.avi'):
    return max(Path(rootpath).glob('**/*{}'.format(ext)),
               key=lambda pth: pth.stat().st_mtime, default='?')
```

Comment: Cool. Did not know this.

Comment: Thanks, I tested this and it worked, but I normally use Python 2 (macOS does not come with Python3 by default!) which does not have the default (also not mentioned in `Learning Python`)